# Find number of cores available in a given node

Tags: scripting, cpu, cut, head, uptime

I need to fix the following piece of code. The code aims to determine the number of cores available in a given node.

**Step 1**: Get the number of cores with

```
TC=$(grep -c process /proc/cpuinfo)
```

**Step 2**: Take the uptime ignoring the decimals

```
LA=$(uptime | cut -d ' ' -f 13 | head -c 1)
```

**Step 3**: Subtract `$LA` from `$TC` to get the number of processes I can run

```
procs=$(expr $TC - $LA)
```

My issue is with Step 2: when I type `uptime | cut -d ' ' -f 13 | head -c 1`, I get `a`. What does that mean? Is there a mistake in step 2?

Let me add that if I type simply `uptime` I get

```
 23:17:01 up 38 days, 38 min,  8 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of `uptime` includes several fields with a variable numbers of spaces.  `cut` treats *every* space as a field separator, so changes to some of those values will mean your `cut` pulls out a different number entirely.

For example, the number of users is space-padded.  When it's less than 10, there are two spaces; when 10 or more, only 1.

```
$ echo ' 23:17:01 up 38 days, 38 min,  8 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00'|cut -d ' ' -f13
average:
$ echo ' 23:17:01 up 38 days, 38 min, 10 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00'|cut -d ' ' -f13
0.00,
```

You could instead use `awk`, which permits a variable amount of space between each field (and ignores space at the beginning of the line):

```
$ echo ' 23:17:01 up 38 days, 38 min,  8 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00' | awk '{print $11}'
```

But this can still break if the number of "words" itself changes, eg. when the uptime itself isn't (just) days and minutes:

```
 14:51:24 up 4 min,  1 user,  load average: 0.17, 0.16, 0.07
 14:52:09 up 6 days, 21:58, 11 users,  load average: 0.79, 0.84, 0.82
```

So the other punctuation marks on the line, commas and colons, can also change, and are no help for finding the numbers you need.

You could use `grep -o ...` to extract only the words `load average:` onwards, and extract the correct word from that.  But it would be far simpler to stop parsing the output of `uptime` entirely, and instead extract the load average from `/proc/loadavg`, if your OS has such a file:

```
$ cat /proc/loadavg
1.01 0.91 0.85 1/793 24545
```

If you only want the first number, ignoring decimals, you can do that with a single `cut`:

```
$ cut -d. -f1 /proc/loadavg
1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your cut command is cutting out the 13th field, but you want the 14th field...

```
⇨  uptime |cut -d ' ' -f 13
average:
```

After that goes through your cut command, you are left with the 'a' character.

Try:

```
⇨  uptime |cut -d ' ' -f 14
0.18
```

Also note, your head -c 1 will cut the decimals off... I think you might be better off rounding up or something. Look at bc perhaps.